# ServiceContractGenerator CodeDomProvider Compile Errors

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, reflection

I am trying to use ServiceCodeGenerator and CodeDomProvider to dynamically create a service reference. When compiling the code using CodeDomProvider it throws the following errors.

It looks like it is only for a specific web service. I am able to compile other web services but this one throws the compile errors below.

Any idea how I can edit the source code or ignore the errors?

> CS0579: Duplicate 'System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute'
>   attribute 99 CS0579: Duplicate
>   'System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute' attribute 101
>   CS0579: Duplicate 'System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute'
>   attribute 191 CS0579: Duplicate
>   'System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute' attribute 193

The code is below:

```
Uri address = new Uri(url + "?wsdl");
        MetadataExchangeClientMode mexMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;
        MetadataExchangeClient metadataExchangeClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(address, mexMode);
        metadataExchangeClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;

        //Trust all certificates
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        ICredentials networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        metadataExchangeClient.HttpCredentials = networkCredential;

        MetadataSet metadataSet = metadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata();
        WsdlImporter wsdlImporter = new WsdlImporter(metadataSet);
        Collection<ContractDescription> contracts = wsdlImporter.ImportAllContracts();
        ServiceEndpointCollection allEndpoints = wsdlImporter.ImportAllEndpoints();

        ServiceContractGenerator serviceContractGenerator = new ServiceContractGenerator();
        foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts)
        {
            serviceContractGenerator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);
        }

        // Generate a code file for the contracts.
        CodeGeneratorOptions codeGeneratorOptions = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
        codeGeneratorOptions.BracingStyle = "C";

        // Create Compiler instance of a specified language.
        CompilerResults compilerResults;
        using (CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {

            // Adding WCF-related assemblies references as copiler parameters, so as to do the compilation of particular service contract.
            CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[] { "System.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll", "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" });

            compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            compilerParameters.WarningLevel = 1;

            compilerResults = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, serviceContractGenerator.TargetCompileUnit);
        }

        if (compilerResults.Errors.Count <= 0)
        {
            assembly = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (CompilerError error in compilerResults.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorNumber + ": " + error.ErrorText + " " + error.IsWarning + " " + error.Line);
            }

            throw new Exception("Compiler Errors - unable to build Web Service Assembly");
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the generator uses its own CodeCompileUnit, and generates classes with same name . It is necessary to force it to use CodeCompileUnit that used by WsdlImporter, for example (Spent a day to find out):

```
Collection<ContractDescription> contracts = importerWsdl.ImportAllContracts();
ServiceEndpointCollection allEndpoints = importerWsdl.ImportAllEndpoints();
CodeCompileUnit unit = (CodeCompileUnit) importerWsdl.State[typeof (CodeCompileUnit)];
ServiceContractGenerator generator = new ServiceContractGenerator(unit);
```

And now we have a full equivalent of "Add Service Reference"

Answer (score 0):

You might need to explicitly remove the **`XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter`** extension from your **WsdlImporter**

Try this..

```
        var wsdlImporter = new WsdlImporter(metadataSet);

        // when you initialize the WsdlImporter with a 'MetadataSet', i
        // the WsdlImporter.WsdlImportExtensions will already be 
        // loaded with 7 or so extensions.
        // one of them being, XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
        // Removing this extension seems to be solving the problem of 
        // Duplicate Data Contracts
        // and Compile errors on Duplicate 'GeneratedCode' attribute etc.

        wsdlImporter.WsdlImportExtensions
                    .Remove(typeof(XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter));
```